# How to calculate (using a program) a column of sums or to test inequalities?

Tags: inequality, math

Each expression is on a separate line.
Given

```
34-2
34-5
34-3
```

I'm looking to obtain

```
34-2=28
34-5=29
34-3=31
```

Or, this would also be helpful:
given:

```
34-2=5
34-5<=34
34-3=31
```

I'm looking to obtain

```
!   34-2=5
    34-5<=34
    34-3=31
```

Where ! is some indication that inequality or equality is false. I'm looking for something that processes text files.

Comment: Importing to a spreadsheet and constructing an appropriate macro wouldn't work for you?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what macro to construct?

Comment: This is more a programming question than a math question. Any programming language that has an `eval` function (e.g. Python, Perl, MATLAB) will be able to do this trivially. For example, if the input file is `so.txt` then in MATLAB I can write `cellfun(@(x)[x '=' num2str(eval(x))],textread('so.txt','%[^\n]'),'UniformOutput',false)` and get the result: `ans = 
    '34-2=32'
    '23+4=27'
    '45-9=36'`, which I could then write to a file.

Answer (score 1):

[Chris Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546084/chris-taylor) is perfectly right, here is what it gives in python:

```
>>> s="""34-2
34-5
34-3
34-2==5
34-5<=34
34-3==31
"""
>>> for line in s.split('\n'):
    # Test line is not empty
    if line:
        operators = ('!=', '<=', '>=', '==', '<', '>')
        op_found = False
        # Stop at 1st operator found
        for op in operators:
            if op in line:
                op_found = True
                if not eval(line):
                    print '!', line
                else:
                    print '+', line
                break
        # If no operator found, we assume we want the result of the operation
        if not op_found:
            print '{0}={1}'.format(line, eval(line))


34-2=32
34-5=29
34-3=31
! 34-2==5
+ 34-5<=34
+ 34-3==31
>>>
```

Several remarks:

- I used `==` instead of `=` because that's the way equality is in python (`=` is only used for assignment)
- I also used `+` to show assertion was right for readability purpose
- I used a string `s` but you can of course use a file (you would replace the line `for line in s.split('\n'):`
   by `for line in open(file_path):`
- keep in mind that each time you use `eval`, you can be hacked (beware of the lines you have in your file...)